# How to Deploy a Token Using the ERC-3643 Standard

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-3643, security-token

I want to develop a smart contract using the ERC-3643 standard instead of ERC-20. Could you guide me on how to integrate this standard into my contract? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've come to the right place, as one of the co-authors of the ERC-3643, I can guide you on how to get started.

First of all, the core contracts of **ERC-3643** include the following:

- `Token`
- `IdentityRegistry` (`IdentityRegistryStorage` is optional)
- `ClaimIssuer`
- `ClaimRegistry`
- `Compliance`.

Here's how you can proceed:

- Official Repo of the **T-REX (ERC-3643)**: at
  https://github.com/TokenySolutions/T-REX for comprehensive
  information on the **ERC-3643** standard.
- Decentralized Identity: **ERC-3643** uses **OnchainID** (https://github.com/onchain-id) for **decentralized identity management**, which is a **crucial** part of the standard
- Understanding Deployment Order: I recommend reading the test files in the T-REX repo to understand how the contracts are deployed and their order. It would be too lengthy to detail here, but examining the tests will give you a clear understanding of the process.
- Continuous Updates: Remember that the **ERC-3643** might have changed since its initial release, as **Tokeny**, the company behind the standard, continuously updates and refines it.

Here is a simple infographic explaining the T-Rex Standard (ERC-3643) from three years ago, Keep in mind that the core principles are still relevant, but some details may have changed or been updated since then:
[image: ERC-3643 (T-Rex) Standard]

Comment: Thanks! How can I verify the identity(addClaim) of the smart contract since I want to transfer the tokens into the smart contract ? Error is : Permissions: Sender does not have claim signer key

Comment: The issuer that has been added to the ClaimIssuer should add a claim to the Identity (sender) that requires the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please send some examples of erc3643 tokens deployed on the ethereum network with their corresponding addresses?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).